# CVCalendar - Changing Circle Background Colors

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I've got CVCalendar working in my project and have done a lot of customizing.  Below is a screen shot.

[Calendar Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7t1E.png)

One of the things I can't figure out how to do is change the color of the circle showing the current date.  Currently it's red, I would like to change it to another color.  I've tried looking through the info on GitHub but cannot find the right setting.  Also, when you select a different date, it changed the current dates text to red and the selected date is circled in a light blue.  I would like to change these colors also and can't figure it out.  Anyone familiar with CVCalendar the can help?

Answer (score 0):

To customize calendar appearance you have to use the methods in CVCalendarViewAppearanceDelegate. You can check all the available methods in [CVCalendar API](https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar/wiki/CVCalendarViewAppearanceDelegate)

I suggest you have a look at

```
func dayLabelBackgroundColor(by weekDay: Weekday, status: CVStatus, present: CVPresent) -> UIColor?
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  I didn't have these parameters in when I originally tried to implement this method.